# Building up URL to include package name in email template

Tags: email, email-template, api-26

I can put a hyperlink to an Opportunity in an email template by doing:

```
<a href="{!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_140, FIND('.com/',$Api.Partner_Server_URL_140)+3)}/{!opportunityId}> link </a>
```

where

```
{!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_140, FIND('.com/',$Api.Partner_Server_URL_140)+3)
```

gets met the server name for the user.

This will look something like:

```
https://na9.salesforce.com/
```

I want to preappend a specific packing into the domain name. Something like:

```
https://mypackage.na9.salesforce.com/
```

Any tips on how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

If your simply linking to a Salesforce record, you don't need to apply your package prefix into the URL. This is typically required if your wanting to reference something specifically from your package, such as a page. Even then, if you have overridden the View for the object your record URL points to, the Salesforce platform will handle the redirect and namespace inclusion for you. So in short, if its just records your linking to, your fine without it! :-)